# Having issue in my if condition in my php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I want to do is when a user click the login button and the inputs are empty its will echo `please enter email and password` and if the user put email and password wrong it will echo `incorrect email and password` .

My problem is when i click the login button and the inputs are empty it echo both `please enter email and password` and `incorrect email and password`.

I want to echo please enter email and password if both email and password are empty only and if one of email or password is wrong it should echo incorrect email and password.

```
<?php

require 'encryption.php';
include_once('database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$hash_cost_log2 = 8;
$hash_portable = FALSE;
$hasher = new PasswordHash($hash_cost_log2, $hash_portable);
$hash = '*';

$login = $db->prepare("SELECT user_password FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email= :email");
$login->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$login->execute();
$hash = $login->fetchColumn();

    if(empty($email) && empty($pass)){
      echo "Please enter Email and Password";
    }
    if($hasher->CheckPassword($pass, $hash))
    {
        $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * from tbl_user WHERE user_email=? AND user_password=? AND user_active='1'");
        $st->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindParam(2, $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount() === 1){
            echo "1";
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        echo "Incorrect Email or Password";  
    }  
?>
```

Comment: `if(empty($email) || empty($pass))` if one or the other is empty, it will trigger the error.

Comment: Either that, or check it on the client side with JS before passing it along to the PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your second `if` to `elseif`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this:

```
if(empty($email) && empty($pass)){
    echo "Please enter Email and Password";
} else {
   if ($hasher->CheckPassword($pass, $hash))
         echo "works"
   } else {
         echo "doesn't work"
   }
}
```